# Get assembly metadata in NDepend

Tags: ndepend

I am trying to create CQL query which will select assemblies created by my company.

In my opinion the easiest way is to check  data generated in AssemblyInfo, but I cannot find how to access it in CQL.

Answer (score 0):

What about the code query:

```
from a in Application.Assemblies
where a.Name.StartsWith("YourCompany.YourProduct")
select a
```

Or do you need something more sophisticated?

---

Ok, what about getting inspiration from [this default rule](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_UI_layer_shouldn%27t_use_directly_DB_types.html):

```
// <Name>UI layer shouldn't use directly DB types</Name>
warnif count > 0

// UI layer is made of types in namespaces using a UI framework
let uiTypes = Application.Namespaces.UsingAny(Assemblies.WithNameIn("PresentationFramework", "System.Windows", "System.Windows.Forms", "System.Web")).ChildTypes()

// You can easily customize this line to define what are DB types.
let dbTypes = ThirdParty.Assemblies.WithNameIn("System.Data", "EntityFramework", "NHibernate").ChildTypes()
              // Ideally even DataSet and associated, usage should be forbidden from UI layer: 
              // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708690/is-list-better-than-dataset-for-ui-layer-in-asp-net
              .Except(ThirdParty.Types.WithNameIn("DataSet", "DataTable", "DataRow"))

from uiType in uiTypes.UsingAny(dbTypes)
let dbTypesUsed = dbTypes.Intersect(uiType.TypesUsed)
select new { uiType, dbTypesUsed }
```

Of course the sets `uiTypes` and `dbTypes` must be refined with assemblies from level N and assemblies from level N+1.

Comment: We have more than 100 assemblies, and I want to create rules for ties, so assembly from tier N+1 can only have dependencies in assemblies from tier N or lower.